# Scala: Why does my tail call optimized code run slower?

Tags: scala, optimization, tail-recursion

Recently I needed to write a functionality to flatten my data structure to a List(). I wrote two functions:

1. Mutable and recursive, and
2. Immutable and tail optimized.

The immutable and tail optimized runs slower. Why?

Here is the code:

This is my recursive data structure from which I would to flatten to List[String]:

```
case class Node[A](rootNode: A, subtree: List[Node[A]])
```

1. This is a mutable solution:

   ```
   def nodeWalk(node: Node[File]): List[String] = {

     val ls = ListBuffer[String]()

     def recurseNodes(node: Node[File]): Unit = {

       node match {
         case Node(r, Nil) => ls += r.getAbsolutePath
         case Node(r, l) =>
           ls += r.getAbsolutePath
           l.map { x => recurseNodes(x) }
       }
     }
     recurseNodes(node)
     ls.toList
   }
   ```
2. This is an immutable and tail optimized solution

   ```
   import scala.util.control.TailCalls._
   def nodeWalk2(node: Node[File]): List[String] = {
     @annotation.tailrec
     def nodeWalker(node: Node[File], acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
       node match {
         case Node(r, List()) =>
           r.getAbsolutePath :: acc
         case Node(r, h :: t) =>
           nodeWalker(Node(h.rootNode, (h.subtree ::: t)), 
                      r.getAbsolutePath :: acc)
       }
     }

     nodeWalker(node, List())
   }
   ```

When I did a micro-benchmark, I get the following results:

```
Type                Items   Time(ms)
------------------------------------
(mutable)           1978       5
(tail optimized)    1978       8

(mutable)           12619      12
(tail optimized)    12619      31

(mutable)           25203      12
(tail optimized)    25203      37

(mutable)           117876     24
(tail optimized)    117876     104

(mutable)           350000     82
(tail optimized)    350000     115
```

Is there any reasonable explanation for why the tail optimized on JVM might be slow? Or is there a problem with my tail-call optimized code? Any suggestions to improve this code are welcome.

Comment: how often did you run the test cases ?  are the numbers averages ? it's a bit strange that for 117876 items the mutable version is 4 times faster while there is almost no difference between 12619 items and 25203.

Comment: I find both versions are totally different. E.g. you are creating new `Node` objects in the first, while you are calling `map` in the second.

Comment: I ran this many times and I consistently see these results. I am as surprised as you looking at these numbers :)

Comment: @ziggystar Are you saying that these are not comparable? I agree that these may not boil down to the same bytecode.

Comment: Probably the main offender is that you are using `:::` on each nearly iteration in the second version. Depending on how your tree is balanced, this can be pretty fast (if most calls happen when the first list is empty) or very slow. And as ziggystar mentioned, creating new nodes instances on each iteration might not help either.

Comment: Also, don't feel obliged to rewrite your first version just to please the gods of purity. You only use a mutable collection (which never leaks outside) internally  and is very short. There's nothing to fix here. For what it's worth, the whole standard collection library is implemented in terms of mutable builders (used only internally as you do). Granted, this is precisely what allows **us** (the library clients) to avoid mutable code while still benefiting from good performances, but you can still use mutable code yourself if needed, and if it does not leak outside there's really no real harm

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I absolutely agree and this was the case I was debating with myself. But out of curiosity, isn't `:::` a O(1) operation? If I am to not copy `Node` how would I do a tail optimized code?

Comment: No, `:::` is O(N) where N is the size of the first list. But to be honest I'm not sure you can do without it in this situation (tailrec + no ref to the parent node). At the very least you could use a more efficient collection to minimize the cost of `:::`. Oh, and there is yet another difference between your two versions: the first one matches against `Nil`, the second one against `List()`. The former is slightly more efficient than the latter (and obviously has nothing to do with whether or not the method is tail recursive...).

Comment: By the way, you probably know this, but a good way to implement this function is `def nodeWalk(node: Node[File]): List[String] = node.rootNode.getAbsolutePath :: node.subtree.flatMap(nodeWalk)`. Well, unless there is a reason to worry about stack overflow.